# Python zfill function adds .0 at the end

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe of numbers that I want to convert to a column with leading zero's using zfill(). The head looks like this:

```
51         5.414940e+12
74         5.414940e+12
123        5.414940e+12
151        8.222312e+11
210        3.830257e+12
219        5.414940e+12
225        2.894138e+10
```

When I use `column.apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(14))`, I get the following output:

```
51         5414939994067.0
74         5414939994067.0
123        5414939994067.0
151         822231182665.0
210        3830257490562.0
219        5414939991684.0
225         028941379627.0
```

which is not what I want... zfill() adds .0 behind and does not work properly.
This is the output that I want:

```
51         05414939994067
74         05414939994067
```

etc.
How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It is working, do you mean that you want to keep the `E+xx` formatting?

Comment: No, I do not want the .0 at the end. And for example, in line 151 the zfill() does not do its job

Comment: It does :) You have floating point numbers that you are converting to strings. Copy and paste one of your numbers into the python prompt and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Can you show your output? When I convert the dataframe to excel it still shows it in the wrong way, with the .0 at the end

Comment: Assuming your column name is 'col' try `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)`.

Comment: I get the following error: 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:'

Comment: Then perhaps first get rid of the `.0` part via `[:-2]` and then `zfill`: `.apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-2].zfill(14))`?

Answer (score 0):

The default representation of a floating point number includes one decimal so you can differentiate it from an integer:

```
>>> str(1.)
'1.0'
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str(2 / 2)
'1.0'
>>> str(2 // 2)
'1'
```

That’s what’s happening when you do `str`. Instead you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#formatspec) to specify the format.

- Fixed floating point is with `f`

  ```
  >>> '{:f}'.format(5.414940e+12)
  '5414940000000.000000'
  ```
- Specify number of digits after the decimal with `.N`, here let’s use 0:

  ```
  >>> '{:.0f}'.format(5.414940e+12)
  '5414940000000'
  ```
- Specify total number of digits before the `.`, let’s go with 14:

  ```
  >>> '{:14.0f}'.format(5.414940e+12)
  ' 5414940000000'
  ```
- Specify which character to fill with (you see above the default is space):

  ```
  >>> '{:014.0f}'.format(5.414940e+12)
  '05414940000000'
  ```

So for your dataframe you can simply do:

```
>>> df
51     5.414940e+12
74     5.414940e+12
123    5.414940e+12
151    8.222312e+11
210    3.830257e+12
219    5.414940e+12
225    2.894138e+10
dtype: float64
>>> df.apply('{:014.0f}'.format)
51     05414940000000
74     05414940000000
123    05414940000000
151    00822231200000
210    03830257000000
219    05414940000000
225    00028941380000
dtype: object
```